# Regex - replace all specific special characters with nothing in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove some specific special characters from my strings and also the letters

These are the special characters `/,-‗‖*<>:;^’+`. This is what I tried:

```
$telephone = preg_replace('[^/,-‗‖*<>:;^’+]', '', $telephone);
```

Example: `adadsdad131231231222/,-‗‖*<>:;^’+22222` , should become: `13123123122222222`

But I am not so good with regex. I tried to find smth similar, with specific characters , but aren't any posts :(  Can you help me with this ?

`UPDATE` Another example:
`adadsdad131231231222/,-‗‖*<&>:;^’+22222` should become `131231231222&22222`

Comment: Are there any non-digit characters that you actually allow?  This is pretty trivial if you only want digits.

Comment: if `^` is the first character in a character set it is inverted,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had these mistakes in your regex:

- `^` in the beginning negates the character class. So, I escaped it with `\`
- `-` in the middle will let you match a range of characters. Hence, I moved it to the end of the character class
- You did not include the range `a-z`

Try this regex:

```
(?i)[\^\/,‗‖*<>:;^’+a-z-]+
```

Replace matches with a blank string

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CA0qUQ/2)

**[Code Result](http://rextester.com/ICJE20673)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - case-insensitive modifier
- `(?i)[\^\/,‗‖*<>:;^’+a-z-]+` - matches either a letter or any of these characters `^`,`/`,`‗`,`‖`,`*`,`<`,`>`,`:`,`;`,`+`,`-`

Comment: I am getting `null` using: `$telephone = preg_replace('(?i)[\^\/,‗‖*<>:;^’+a-z-]+', '', $telephone);`. Did I miss smth ?

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/CA0qUQ/2/codegen?language=php) in the link to the code